# JsonObjectRequest and RequestQueue error

Tags: android, json, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

SOLUTION: my problem was with the context, in case anyone else has the same problem.

I am trying to make a request in my android app with JsonObjectRequest and RequestQueue with Volley lib but I am getting an error continuously.

First, I tried to use just JsonObjectRequest (without RequestQueue) but I didn't get any data so I tried to use RequestQueue.

- Here is my code:

  ```
     JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlMarket, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
              try {
                  JSONArray result = response.getJSONArray("result");
                  //we loop the response
                  for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                      coin.setHigh(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("High")));
                      coin.setLow(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Low")));
                      coin.setLast(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Last")));
                      coin.setVolInBtc(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("BaseVolume")));
                      coin.setBid(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Bid")));
                      coin.setAsk(Double.parseDouble(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("Ask")));
                      coin.setPrevDay(result.getJSONObject(i).getString("PrevDay"));


                  }
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

          }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
              error.printStackTrace();
          }
      });

      requestQueue.add(request);
  ```
- That is the way I initialize requestQueue:

  ```
     requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
  ```
- This is the error I am getting:

  ```
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{space.bewa.bewa_v10/space.bewa.bewa_v10.activities.DashboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()' on a null object reference
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getCacheDir()' on a null object reference
                                                                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:43)
                                                                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:78)
  ```

  Any kind of help would be very appreciated

Comment: may be your `context` is null

Comment: post the full code of the class

Comment: have you initialized context as Context context=this;

Comment: Both of you are right! It was the context! Thanks :)

Comment: There are better options than Volley if you have a choice https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7nmtzy/reddits_official_app_uses_volley/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**as per my above comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076348/jsonobjectrequest-and-requestqueue-error#comment83126389_48076348)

You `context` is `null`

Intialize your `context` like this

```
Context context=YourActivity.this;
```

or

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: You're supposed to use application context for request queue